# How can I add a custom extension tag to the GPXFramework code?

Tags: ios, xml, frameworks, gps, gpx

I found the excellent resource of the open source iOS GPX Framework (http://gpxframework.com/) which allows me to create and read GPX files. However I would like to add a custom extension to store data specific to my app. I can see that the GPX framework implements a file GPXExtensions.h and .m, but I am not sure how to go about adding say a tag for storing the speed data at a particular coordinate in the GPX. 
I am guessing I would have to add the data I would like to add as an extension to the GPXExtensions class as a property and then somehow modify the code in this method:

```
- (void)addChildTagToGpx:(NSMutableString *)gpx indentationLevel:(NSInteger)indentationLevel
{
    [super addChildTagToGpx:gpx indentationLevel:indentationLevel];
}
```

But I am not sure what this method is supposed to do, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's basically the right idea.  Jaime Machuca's fork contains a [commit](https://github.com/jmachuca77/iOS-GPX-Framework/commit/9c3b091a541882a69badeb6080bf076bbf7b5c99) where he added heart rate, etc.  It  should give you a pretty good template from which to create your own modifications. Note that if you want something more sophisticated, you may need to create your own subclass of GPXElement so that you can take advantage of the tree structure.